# How to preserve \ when converting a string to a RegEx

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have some regex that are coming to me via JSON object, like so:

```
{
  config: { 
    regEx: "/^$/"
  }
}
```

I am trying to convert the above string into a regex, like so:

```
const re = new RegExp(config.regEx);
```

This works, but `RegExp` is ~helpfully~ escaping the `/` characters and returning `//^$//` (not `/^$/`)

How can I best turn the string into a regex without escaping the `/`?

EDIT: I have no control over the original string returned. It is what it is.

Comment: Trim those, the `RegExp` constructor assumes the expression literally without delimiters. So you need to pass a `"^$"` string instead.

Comment: It's not escaping the `/`. It does not need to: `/` is not special in a regex.

Comment: the forward slash `/` is part of the JavaScript regex syntax for the language. It is not part of the regex. You should either never store it in your object, or strip it out of the string before you construct the regex.

Comment: If you have a `/` in your regex, but you don't want to match a literal `/`, you need to strip that `/` out beforehand.

Comment: I don't understand the question title; it sounds like you're asking how to remove the first and last character from a string, not "preserve \"?

Comment: @ChrisG FYI, the edit you made actually doesn't capture the full nature of the asker's question. Some environments will show `//^$//` instead of the version with backslash-escaped inner slashes (Chrome's DevTools console, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `/`'s around you regex, like so : `"/^$/"` becomes `"^$"`.

The `/`'s around your regex when not using regexp constructor are simply the way to tell javascript (v8) that it's a regex, the same way `"`'s tell javascript that it's a string. (I can see why this might confuse you due to the fact that `/^$/.toString()` results in `"/^$/"`)

To remove the `/`'s from the string do this:

```js
config.regEx.replace(/(^\/)|(\/$)/g, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

*Escaping* is not exactly the word for what's going on here.

When composing a RegEx with an inline definition, it's normally impossible (without a backslash) to include a forward slash at the start of the expression, since the double slash would be interpreted as a comment.

```js
let re = //abc/g;
```

This is where `new RegExp()` comes into play. You can feed the function a *string* and it will encapsulate the contents into a RegEx -- *without evaluating the contents*.

So really, what you're seeing in the console is not *escaping*, but rather two different types of slashes in succession:

1. The outer slashes that denote the RegEx, then
2. The inner slashes that are part of your encapsulated string.

Short of using `eval()`, there's no way to use a string to define a regular expression in such a way that the slashes are interpreted as its "bounds". *Please* don't use `eval()`.

The simplest way to get your intended behavior is to just strip off the first and last characters of the string you're passing in like so:

```js
const re = new RegExp(config.regEx.slice(1,-1));
```

If you want to trim off the slashes conditionally, you could (ironically) use a regular expression:

```js
const TRIM_SLASH = new RegExp('^/(.*)/$');
let stripped = config.regEx.replace(TRIM_SLASH,'$1');
const re = new RegExp(stripped);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the pattern is stored doesn't seem to be designed for javascript, so you have to extract the eventual global modifiers and to remove the delimiters:

```
let toto = {
  config: { 
    regEx: "/^$/"
  }
};

let delimiter = toto.config.regEx[0];
let arr = toto.config.regEx.split(delimiter);

arr.shift();

let modifiers = arr.pop();
let pattern = arr.join(delimiter);

/* eventually, you need to escape backslashes (depending of how patterns
   are written, if it isn't the case already):
pattern = pattern.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'); */

const re = new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
```